# dictionary in template tag django

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to extract something like bellow:

```
{% for item in query_ %}
 <td>{{ mydictionary[item.id] }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

which of course gives me a syntax error. For this purpose I have defined a template tag

```
@register.filter('get_value_from_dict')
def get_value_from_dict(dict_data, key):
    if key:
        return dict_data.get(key)
```

and then use it as follows:

```
{% for item in query_ %}
 <td>{{ mydictionary | get_value_from_dict : item.id }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

however it doesnt work and gives me the following error:

```
get_value_from_dict requires 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

I was wondering what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the spacing. You should not add spaces around the colon (`:`), you thus can fix this with:

```
{{ mydictionary|get_value_from_dict:item.id }}
```

Comment: thanks this helped the function to run, now it gives another error.**  'str' object has no attribute 'get' **. my key is an string, I am not sure how to get around this

Comment: `mydictionary` is apparently *not* a dictionary, but a string... You thus will need to look to the view where you pass `mydictionary`.